# How many times does Ruby evaluate a loop's enumerated collection?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, if I were to loop over a collection, how many times would Ruby evaluate the enumerated collection?

Specifically, I'd like to sort a collection, and loop over the sorted collection. Since I have no need for keeping a copy of the sorted collection around, I figured I'd just write the loop as:

```
for item in @items.sort{ |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at } do
    #do some stuff
end
```

However, after crafting that lovely bit of code I began to wonder how many times I might be actually calling sort.

Would the above line indeed only sort the collection once? Or will Ruby end up sorting it N times for each item in the collection?

Comment: @sepp2k showed in his second example the more idiomatic `@items.sort...` form of looping over a collection. I don't think I've seen anyone use a for/loop in Ruby in all the source I've read. I'm not sure why but maybe it's just the Ruby way.

Comment: @Greg, thank you. I am still learning 'the Ruby way', and Ruby's numerous looping constructs simply amaze me. I've never seen language with so many different ways to iterate.

Comment: Ruby is the most freeing language I've ever used; I've heard it referred to as zen-like a couple times. I don't think it's for everyone, but for those whose brains it fits it's very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `sort` once.

Except for scoping differences,

```
for x in xs do
  some_stuff
end
```

is the same as

```
xs.each do |x|
  some_stuff
end
```

And of course when you do `foo.bar(baz)`, `foo` is evaluated exactly once, no matter what `bar` does.

Comment: 'x' will retain its value after the for loop ends in the first example, the same is not true of the second example.

Comment: @EdSwangren: That's what I meant by "scoping differences".

Comment: thank you for clarifying that. After reading @sepp2k answer I was curious what different scoping they had. I was actually reading through some other SO questions to see if I could find that answer. Thank you both, you actually answered two questions I had, I didn't even think to ask the .each loop one :-D

Answer (score 1):

That's equivalent to sorting the whole collection once, and then iterating it once.

Equivalent to:

```
@items.sort{ |a,b| b.created_at <=> a.created_at }.each do |item|
  # do some stuff
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Even cleaner and much faster:

```
@items.sort_by {|a| a.created_at}.reverse
```

You should pretty much always use `sort_by` instead of `sort` if you can (and you almost always can), because it evaluates the sort-key function only once per item. And it lets you write half as much comparison code!

Comment: Be careful using `sort_by` instead of `sort`. Sort_by has more overhead by default and if you're doing a simple comparison that overhead can overwhelm the possible speed-up, resulting in significantly slower sort times. `sort_by` is for when you are doing a costly lookup or calculation to find the actual keys for sorting, and will gain because of its caching of the intermediate results. I was doing some benchmarks last night on 1.9.2, and `sort` was 8x faster than `sort_by` for normal comparisons. It would take a pretty expensive lookup to make `sort_by` faster.

Comment: What was your actual comparison? I just timed `sort_by {|x| x[:key]}` vs `sort {|x,y| x[:key] <=> y[:key]}`, which is about as simple as it gets, and sort_by was more than twice as fast as sort. But that was 1.9.1, so there's another variable.